# Python: Importing from a running instance, or an alternative

Tags: python, instance, python-import

I have 2 files, data.py and interpret.py.

data.py:

```
X = cPickle.load(open("X","r"))
```

interpret.py:

```
from data import X
query = raw_input("Enter query")

#do something with query and X
```

Object X which is very huge. I dumped it using cPickle. 
interpret.py will be invoked by another program and because of the way import currently works, everytime interpret.py is executed, it loads data.py which loads X, and since X is very big it takes a lot of time.

I want to be able to do something like this.

data.py:

```
from time import sleep
X = cPickle.load(open("X","r"))
sleep(10**10) #Sleep for eternity
```

and then run data.py

interpret.py:

```
from data import X #import from live instance of data.py
                   #don't load X all over again
query = raw_input("Enter query")

#do something with query and X
```

How can I do this? If I cannot import from a live instance, is there an alternative to do what I want to do. I am not communicating very well, please tell me which parts you don't understand and I will try to clarify further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell you want to be running a daemon. For instance instead of importing data from interpret, data would run as a standalone daemon which interpret would communicate with over something like a socket.

But at this point you've basically written a database, so why not just translate whatever data you have into some database and just communicate with a database?

Edit: The problem is that you want the huge object to persist between processes, but it can't work like that persay. Every time you call intepret, a new process is spawned which means that there is no access to the object generated by the previous process. That's why daemons (and databases) exist.

Comment: I really do not want to add another layer, which is database. But I guess you are right. Can you suggest a way for python programs to communicate between each other, ie invoke each other's functions while still running?

I used to do this by communicating through stdin, but that would be messy, because there would be multiple instances of interpret.py running, I just wanted the system to handle multithreading and not get into that, which would be needed if I add another database

Comment: No, not really in your use case. Separate processes can communicate through sockets, unix sockets, named pipes, and things like that. Again I would suggest using a database. It will make it much easier and much less complex. (because again, no matter what way you are approaching it,  what you basically want to do is write a database. And there are much better coders than you or I that have already written one.)

Comment: I guess you are right. It was for one of my projects and adding another layer would mean changing all our previous documents [architecture views, drivers, requirements etc], but I guess I can workaround. THanks

Answer (score 1):

To get this to work the way you want you need to keep your entire Python program running so instead of having your other program execute interpret.py as a script each time you will need to set it up so that interpret.py is executed once and each time your program needs to make a query it uses that existing instance.py program.

You can probably just do something like this for interpret.py:

```
from data import X
while True:
    query = raw_input("Enter query")

    #do something with query and X
```

Your other program can then write a line to stdin of the interpret.py program it is running each time it needs to make a query.

Comment: The other program I am talking about is a php file that was supposed to call interpret, which is gonna be implemented by my friend. Can you please suggest another way for a php file and interpret to communicate, instead of using stdin? Thank you

Comment: You could have data.py run as a daemon as I suggested, and then have the php script communicate directly with the daemon over a socket (skipping interpret all together.)